# JAR generated using JarOutputStream with invalid .class

Tags: java, jar

My goal is take the stream of some .classes and create a JAR.

The problem is that JAR created stores the .classes but can not be used as a classpath (it just do not find the class). The JAR is not corrupted and if I uncompress the JAR, I can use the .classes.
So, what is the problem if this code?

```
@Test
public void createJARTest() throws IOException
{
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final JarOutputStream jarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream( byteArrayOutputStream );

    final String path = "/com/app/MyClass.class";

    final JarEntry entry = new JarEntry( path );
    jarOutputStream.putNextEntry( entry );

    final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream( this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path) );

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ( (bytesRead = in.read( buffer )) != -1 )
    {
        jarOutputStream.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
    }
    in.close();
    jarOutputStream.closeEntry();

    jarOutputStream.close();

    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo( new FileOutputStream("/Downloads/classpath.jar") );
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

The JarOutputStream has three undocumented quirks:

1. Directory names must end with a '/' slash.
2. Paths must use '/' slashes, not '\'
3. Entries may not begin with a '/' slash.

So, the solution was just change a line:

```
final JarEntry entry = new JarEntry( "com/app/MyClass.class" );
```